# ¿Ayuda para entender el siguiente metodo?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente metodo en mi programa, y aunque lo entiendo un poco no logro capturar su logica completamente soy novato con la programacion de Java.Swing y NetBeans y estoy aprendiendo solo pero al parecer el metodo es un poco complejo y/o avanzado por tanto no logro comprender bien el metodo es el siguiente:

```
private void lastNametxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        InputMap im = lastNametxt.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false), "ADD BUTON");
    ActionMap ap = lastNametxt.getActionMap();
    ap.put("ADD BUTON", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            btnAdd.doClick();

            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    });

}
```

Lo que pretendo hacer con esto es que al presionar ENTER en un determinado JTextField active un boton determinado. Funciona pero no lo comprendo.

Comment: Dentro del método le estamos diciendo que cree un mapa de entrada, en el JTextField cuando esté puesto el foco sobre el.. Después le estamos indicando una combinación de teclas, con una clave 'ADD BUTON'. Después le estamos indicando un mapa de acción que trabajará sobre el JTextField y le indicamos la acción que no es otra 'que la acción de apretar y soltar un botón'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Saludos,

El código que nos compartes hace referencia a una "técnica" llamada [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) que básicamente permite a cualquier componente (que sea extendido de un `JComponent`) responder al ingreso de teclas presionadas por el usuario.

Algo muy similar a esto es el uso del [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), aunque parece más fácil configurar un `KeyListener` que configurar los `Key Bindings` (ya que a primera vista parece complejo) la verdad es que no es así y además el uso de `Key Bindings` te da muchas ventajas. Todo queda a tu disposición cuál utilizar.

Acá te dejo un [link de otra respuesta de como utilizar Key Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22741216/8954823) (aunque está en inglés a mí me ayudó bastante).

Volviendo al tema, básicamente el uso de `Key Bindings` se realiza con dos clases: [InputMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputMap.html) y [ActionMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ActionMap.html).

La clase `InputMap` nos permite "unir" (binding) o "relacionar" un evento de ingreso de teclas con un Objeto. Mientras que la clase `ActionMap` nos permite relacionar dichos objetos con acciones que se deben realizar.

El parámetro que ingresaste al obtener el `InputMap` de tu objeto `JTextField` indica cuándo debe "accionarse". Normalmente se utilizan 3 condiciones:

- `JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED`: Cuando el componente tiene el enfoque del teclado.
- `JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`: Cuando el componente contiene (o es) el componente que tiene el enfoque.
- `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`: Cuando tu aplicación tiene el enfoque (es decir, cuando no hay otra aplicación enfocada) o bien, contiene el componente que tiene el enfoque.

En tu caso le indicaste que se "accionara" si tu `JTextField` tiene el enfoque, es decir, si otro componente posee el enfoque del teclado, las acciones no se ejecutarán.

---

Al hacer esto:

```
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false), "ADD BUTON");
```

Estás indicando que se agregará una nueva relación, el primer parámetro que ingresaste (`KeyStroke`) es el evento de tecla, el cuál nos indica 3 cosas:

- La tecla presionada (en tu caso es la tecla ENTER).
- Los modificadores (si debe admitir teclas especiales como SHIFT, CTRL, ALT...), si este queda en '0' se indica que no se agregará ningún modificador.
- Si es `true` indica si se debe accionar al soltar la tecla. Caso contrario, se acciona al presionarla.

Y el segundo parámetro, es el objeto al cual se hará la relación. Podría tomarse como un identificador (para saber cómo se llamará el evento).

Por otro lado, al hacer esto:

```
ap.put("ADD BUTON", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        btnAdd.doClick();
    }
});
```

Estás agregando una acción (`AbstractAction`) a dicho objeto (`ADD BUTON`). Donde la acción a ejecutar es la que se encuentra definida en el método `actionPerformed`.

Básicamente, con esto concluimos que el `Key Binding` que has configurado en tu objeto `JTextField` accionará un botón de agregado al presionar la tecla ENTER cuando tengas el enfoque sobre tu objeto `JTextField`.